# Find_each with hkeys on Redis in Ruby on Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis

I need to do something like a find_each on rails with redis.

I need to take for example, the values with limit of 100 registries, and, when i pass the paginate 2, i get other 100 registries.

I'm getting the values with HKEYS method in rails...

`Model.redis.hkeys(:keysofvalues)`

I saw the redis documentation and i didn't found nothing with say how it works.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Taken from [Redis HKEYS command](https://redis.io/commands/hkeys):

> Returns all field names in the hash stored at key.

So Redis by itself doesn't support pagination.

You can get keys from redis and paginate is manually using [Kaminari](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari). Look at this [How do I paginate an Array?](https://github.com/kaminari/kaminari/wiki/Kaminari-recipes#-how-do-i-paginate-an-array)

Answer (score 0):

Redis' hash datatype is ill-suited for data that has so many key/value pairs that you'd want to paginate them, which is why there is no function that allows pagination. (Redis tends to make it hard to shoot yourself in the foot.)

If you need pagination, you'd probably want to use *lists*, which allow accessing elements at any position with *O(N)* complexity.